# Move li to ul on conditions.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very sorry if i opened it again but i tested some codes as you told me:
this is what i have done at last:

```
<script>
if( $('#nav ul li').length > 5 )
{
$('#nav li:gt(4)').appendTo('ul.more');
}
</script>
```

but it didnt work.
this is what i want to get

```
<ul class='mymenu'>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>More Button</li>
                <ul>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't get that. It's invalid html structure, you can't have `<li>` and `<ul>` next to each other. In this case the `ul` should be in `li`.

Comment: Where is `#nav`? Where is `ul.more`?

Comment: @Shomz its in my code i will share my orginal code nw. in a new link

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job (edited)

```
<script>
    if( $('#nav ul li').length > 5 )
    {
        $('#nav ul li:eq(3)').after('<li>More Button</li><li><ul class="more">');
        $('#nav ul').append('</ul></li>');
    }
</script>
```

Edited according BlackSheeps hint:

```
<script>
    if( $('#nav ul li').length > 5 )
    {
        $('#nav ul li:gt(3)').wrap('<li><ul class="more"></ul></li>');
        $('#nav ul li:eq(3)').after('<li>More Button</li>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This will still give him an invalid html structure!

Comment: You can't append the opening/closing tags separately. That's not how DOM works!